# Is there any plugin like gitlens for perforce?

Tags: visual-studio-code, perforce, p4v, p4vs

GITLENS is pretty cool plugin I found for Visual Studio Code which give all the information about who and when the changes were made in the file. Is there any similar plugin to GITLENS for Perforce ?
The plugin could be for any other IDE as well.

Answer (score 1):

The extension [Perforce for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=slevesque.perforce) has annotations that can show which changes were made and which user made them.

You can enable annotations for every file by setting the configuration `perforce.annotate.enable` to `true`.

`perforce.annotate.changelist` and `perforce.annotate.user` can be set to `true` to output changelist numbers for each line and the user who modified the line respectively.

Comment: {  
"perforce.annotate.enable": true,
"perforce.annotate.changelist": true,
"perforce.annotate.user": true
}

I have added this to user settings but still I couldn't see any change

Comment: same for me. added this to user settings but still I couldn't see any change

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a new extension [Perforce for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mjcrouch.perforce), You can use the command `perforce.annotate`

By default, it comes with a keybinding `alt`+`p` `n` (it works only when editor text is in focus). You can also search for `Perforce: Annotate` in `Command Palette`.